# Call JavaScript of parent window from child window

Tags: javascript, jquery, popupwindow

I have a calendar and when I click on a `<td>`, a pop-up window appears so you can create your evenement for the date you selected. I want to add a feature.

When the user finishes creating the event, I want to send a JavaScript request to the parent page so I can refresh the calendar using AJAX. Basically, I want to call a function from the child, but the function is on the parent page.

On Google, I only found a script that can refresh the parent window – nothing about a “parent callback”. ☹ Is it even possible?

P.S. The answer can be pure JS or jQuery, it doesn’t matter. I’ll keep looking in the meanwhile.

Comment: @Neal David said he Googled for things like "parent callbacks", which I think, if his search was thorough, is a reasonable amount of effort. Note that, as far as I can tell, David's not asking for complete code to update and display a calendar. He's just asking for a general way for a pop-up window to call a function in its parent window.

Comment: This is a very valid question that has been thrown around a lot, I don't know why it was downvoted. I can imagine that in the coming versions of browsers we will see javascript being able to interact with the windowing platform on a more in-depth level.

Comment: Thanks you both for defending this question. I am just asking a "how-to" but no need for code ... And yes, I did some researches and all I found is how ti refrech the parent window. I have found nothing. Now I hope that in the future this question can be top search in Google and help more people in needs.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What you're looking for is a reference to the `window` that opened the popup window. Once you have that, you can call functions in that window, read and write variables in that window, or even manipulate its DOM.

That reference is called `opener`. It gives you the `window` object for the window that opened the current window. For example, if you have a function in the original window like this:

```
function updateMe( data ) {
    alert( data );
}
```

then in the popup window you could call it like this:

```
opener.updateMe( 'Hello!' );
```

Naturally, you need to make sure that `updateMe()` is a global function in the original page. Or if you have some object in the original page and `updateMe()` is a method of that object, you can still do it, as long as the object is global. e.g. in the host page:

```
var myObject = {
    updateMe: function( data ) {
        alert( data );
    }
};
```

then in the popup you could do:

```
opener.myObject.updateMe( 'Hello!' );
```

Basically, as long as you could get to the object or function in the original page with `window.whatever`, then in the popup you can simply change that to `opener.whatever`.

Comment: MDN's [documentation for `window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.opener)

Comment: Thanks you. From what I see, this is what I was looking for. I will try it tomorrow at work!

Comment: It works like a charm ! Thank a lot, I've learn something today !